# NO update possible

Tags: updates

I got Ubuntu Focal Fossa. Whenever I get the note that an update is ready I click the install now button it shows:The repository https// mirror.famaserver.com ubuntu/archive focal Release does not have a Release file Updating fromsuch a repository cannot be done securely and is therefore disabled by default.

Comment: This appears to be a PPA you added. Remove it and all should be good.

Comment: Did you copy paste this repository from somewhere? It is obviously malformed since it is missing `:` after https and there are whitespaces before mirror. @David This is repository not a PPA (Personal Package Archives).

Comment: @Kulfy thanks I did say appears to be was not sure.